# Why my PPO RL Agent action still passing the upper and lower limit in Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, simulink, reinforcement-learning

I am using default Matlab rappresentation of PPO Agent, I want that one of my action only in range 0 -  1 and the other in range -1 - 1. I already set up my UpperLimit to 1, and LowerLimit to 0 or -1.

```
obsInfo = rlNumericSpec([17 1]);
actInfo = rlNumericSpec([5 1], ...
    "UpperLimit", 1, ...
    "LowerLimit",[0; -1; -1; -1; -1]);
env = rlSimulinkEnv("test_2", "test_2/agent",obsInfo, actInfo, "UseFastRestart", "off");
ppo_opt = rlPPOAgentOptions("SampleTime", 0.01);
agent_ppo = rlPPOAgent(obsInfo, actInfo, ppo_opt);
```

But as you can see, my action still can passing the limit (scope 1 should be in range 0 - 1 , scope 5 in range -1 - 1). This
happen for all action signal. If I change my Agent (e.g. with DDPG) this not happen. How can i fix that ?
[Scope rapresenting two action dynamic of RL Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eset.png)

Answer (score 0):

If ur actor is in continuous space, it will have two out puts. One is mean and second is standard devation. If standard devation path on ur actor gives posetiva value, ur actor will deviate randomly, the larger the standard devation the larger the devation. So try to make standard devation path of ur actor give zero value. Eg if sd=0.1, mean =0, then think as if actual out out is between -0.1 and 0.1.( it's just an example not exact calculation)